# Can I find out who is +1ing my website?

Tags: google-plus-one

So I finally took the plunge and added a +1 button next to the Facebook "like" and Twitter "follow" buttons on most of my websites.  The +1 count seems to be going up but I'm wondering if I can tell who is doing the +1ing

Comment: Its 2014 and I have yet to see who besides myself does g+ on my blog when I g+ my own posts. The only time I see who does g+ is when I don't, and they do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think I've seen anything about a full-on reporting utility around +1s. (Yet?) But if what you're looking for, like site name, is unique enough, you can fudge this a bit with a site-limited search, eg. http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aplus.google.com+techcrunch

But that requires that users have made their +1s public so they show up in the tab, and also searches across their *entire* profile, so you'll also get people who have the term in their Posts or Buzz tabs, too. Depending upon whether you specifically want *only* +1s or just want to see who's supporting you, that may not actually be a bad thing. Obviously people who aren't publicizing their +1s won't be  returned by this, but then they probably wouldn't be by any other method either, I guess.

Just last week, someone in the Google Webmaster forum [suggested](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=35ca192e81782a11&hl=en) it'd be possible to grab identities through the button and a Google employee popped in basically saying "okay, prove it." Given it would've been simple enough for him to just confirm(if that were the case), I'm going to guess the real answer to your question is either no, or that it at least shouldn't be possible at the moment.

Comment: Great response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some analytics on +1s (as well as Facebook/Twitter), give [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com) a try. You can easily add those 3 services and they also include decent analytics for shares and clickbacks.

Answer (score -1):

You are going on right track. By adding +1 to your website you are being social. Its better to active on Google plus as well. As Google started counting your social presence to increase your ranking , you should work on social media as well.