# Confirm that someone has Google +1 'd a link

Tags: google-plus-one

I'm considering a campaign for my existing customers that would offer them a discount on products when they +1 our site. Is there a way to prove that someone has +1'd our site?

Comment: probably not, see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17281/can-i-find-out-who-is-1ing-my-website

Comment: I hope there is no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my purposes the identity of the person isn't as important as proving that the action was taken. Google offers a callback function which I've used to show a confirmation "promotion code" via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If they are using a public google profile, then their +1's can be viewed. I can still see mine when logged out on my [profile](https://profiles.google.com/pritaeas/plusones) page.