# How do I view all the people who have +1ed my site?

Tags: google, google-plus-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I find out who is +1ing my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17281/can-i-find-out-who-is-1ing-my-website)

I have a +1 button on [my blog](http://thegeektechblog.blogspot.com/) and I'd like to be able to see who has +1ed my blog posts. How do I view all the people who have +1ed a page?

Comment: @paulmorriss Yes. It is a dup and I've flagged it as such. I have no idea how I missed that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/google-1-button/OtpyCl14yaM) it is "stipulated" that you cannot see everyone who plused one. 
I think you can see only who clicked on the button if it's in your circles. 
However you should read [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17281/can-i-find-out-who-is-1ing-my-website), as your question might be a duplicate.